# Return boolean in for-loop evaluating multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to iterate over multiple text articles, comparing whether these articles have keywords in 2 disparate lists.  If the article has a keyword from both lists, then it should return 'true.' If an article only has a keyword from one list, then it should be 'false'.

Note: I'm breaking down a larger for-loop into smaller bits to see if I can get it to work, which is why I'm not splitting this into 2 for loops which would check each list and return a '1' for each and then subsetting out anything less than a '2'...which still may be the way to go even if it's a large dataset?

Example of Data:

```
Data:
Text                                  result                
The co-worker ate all of the candy.    False
Bluejays love peanuts.                 False
Westies will eat avocado, even figs.   True
```

Here is my code, but I'm struggling with my for loop.

```
def z(etext):
words = ['candy', 'chocolate', 'mints', 'figs', 'avocado']
words2 = ['eat', 'slurp', 'chew', 'digest']
for keywords in words and words2:
    return True

df['result'] = df['Keyterm'].apply(z)
```

This code returns 'true' for every row of my dataframe, which is not correct. Each row has a list of text in it.

EDIT: The solution:
   
    `def z(etext):
    words = ['candy', 'chocolate', 'mints', 'figs', 'avocado']
    words2 = ['eat', 'slurp', 'chew', 'digest']
    for keyword in words:
        index = etext.find(keyword)
        if index != -1:
           for anotherword in words2:
               index2 = etext.find(anotherword)
               if index2 != -1:
               return True`

```
df['result'] = df['Text'].apply(z)
```

Comment: Your code has some challenges.  Things like, the indenting is broken.  Also what is`keywords`?

Answer (score 0):

what about

> Westies will eat avocado, even figs.   [eat, avocado, figs]

which has multiple keyterms, do you want to check each one of them. I mean return True when each keyterm is present in both lists or what?

Check if the solution works for you?

```
Text = ["The co-worker ate all of the candy.",  "Bluejays love peanuts.","Westies will eat avocado, even figs."]
Keyterm = [["candy"], [], ["eat", "avocado", "figs"]]
data = pd.DataFrame({'Text': Text, 'Keyterm': Keyterm}) 

words = ['candy', 'chocolate', 'mints', 'figs', 'avocado']
words2 = ['eat', 'slurp', 'chew', 'digest', 'candy', 'figs']

def checkList(word, lists):
    if word in lists:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def z(etext):
    res = []
    for keyword in etext:
        ############# Using function checkList here ##############
        if checkList(keyword, words) and checkList(keyword, words2):
            res.append(True)
        else:
            res.append(False)
    return res
data['result'] = data['Keyterm'].apply(z)
```

Comment: I don't understand the first function (def checkList)..this is never applied to the data field?

Comment: I am using first function (chckList) to make sure a word from Keyterm exists in a particular list, because you may have many lists not just words and words2. And i dont understand why you are saying "this is never applied to the data field"?

Comment: I request you to please run the code and let me know if solution works, or let me know the format in which you want the solution. I will update my answer. Thanks

Comment: It didn't work, potentially because I didn't understand which part of the data to implement the list. I think this solution may also be a bit challenging, since I'm going through >1M articles.

Comment: Okay instead of for loop you can use vectorised calculations using pandas. but thats not an issue, first you got to tell me by running the above code did you get the desired output if not please write down what do you expect your output to be.